How is the city power grid routed and connected to individual locations such as houses?
I'm an electrical engineer but I don't know enough about the power distribution grid or civil. I'm no electrician either.
My initial question is how does a new construction, like a home, get safely connected to the city mains? Is there some sort of "main breaker", not the 100+A breaker in the panel, but outside the house? Seems unlikely?
And then that got me thinking about the city grid in general. I know there are giant main disconnects at power stations, but how were all the power lines routed in the first place? Surely they didn't route an entire network of power lines before flipping the main disconnect.
And if you needed to add to a circuit, such as a new construction in an existing area or extending power lines, how do you do that?
Thanks, I'm just curious 

Your house (and those of your nearby neighbors) are served by a transformer which takes the local high-voltage transmission line (10 to 20 kilovolts) and produces 110 volt AC and 220 volt AC which is routed into your home through a drop which is a wire running from the transformer to a short pole on top of your roof. From there the wire goes down to a master disconnect switch and then to a box full of individual switches (usually inside your garage) that turn on or off a bunch of individual circuits inside the house.
The transformer's output goes through a fuse (which is a thin stick of aluminum) before the drop wires. By pulling out the fuse from its holder using a long, insulated stick with a grabber on its end, the drop can be disconnected from the transformer- and your power goes off. Every drop has its own fuse.
The high-voltage lines also have fuses in them at intervals along the line, which can be pulled to isolate the central power source from an entire neighborhood of houses.
This series of fuses and switches running all the way through the distribution network allows the repair guys to interrupt power anywhere in the network so work can safely be done on high-voltage wires, local transformers, power drops and even circuits within a single home.
It is possible to combine a fuse with a disconnect switch to result in a handy device called a breaker. The breaker senses overloads and automatically disconnects the power to reduce the chances of fire.  Once the fault condition is resolved, the breaker can be reset by hand to restore power. the breaker can also be flipped by hand anytime you wish to disconnect power to the circuits served by it.

In my area, the "drop" fuses/disconnects can be anywhere, depending on when the building was built. May be at the transformer, may be outside at the roof, may be inside upstream of the meter.

As a new build site is prepped, the new power lines to extend the existing grid are laid. Once ready, either connections are made live (often based on the voltage) or that portion of the grid is shut down by those power station disconnects that you mention.
Live connections like that are not much of an issue as the new portion does not have any loads on it yet so there is no "spark" or "flash" to content with.
As for disconnecting a house from the grid, then there are fuses that are between the 100A breaker you mention in the fusebox or distribution board which can be removed when certain work is needed. These fuses are sealed, or tagged, and your contract with the electricity company means that they can test your house to see it meets the standards before they reconnect the fuses and retag them.
My parents house had an inspection recently - the electricity company just sent an appointment through that they wanted to test. That test was the first time since the meters were installed over 50 years ago. The meter was updated at that visit :) at their cost. Dad was pleased because all my work replacing circuits was tested and passed. Amusingly, the people doing the test said it was neater than many installations by "professional" companies work that they see.
